# EhCache 3 CacheEntries and HeapSize

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, ehcache, ehcache-3, ehcache-2

I'm moving from EhCache 2 to EhCache3 ,a spring boot java application.
For monitoring of Cache, I'm looking for Cache entries and heap size metric from EhCache 3.
In EhCache2, I had these metrics via prometheus: (cache_size, cache_local_heap_size_bytes)

How can I get these with EhCache 3?

Here's my xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
        xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.1.xsd
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.1.xsd">

    <service>
        <jsr107:defaults enable-management="false" enable-statistics="true"/>
    </service>

    <cache-template name="default">
        <expiry>
            <ttl>600</ttl>
        </expiry>
    </cache-template>

    <cache alias="employee" uses-template="default">
        <resources>
            <heap>1000</heap>
        </resources>
    </cache>

    <cache alias="org" uses-template="default">
        <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
        <resources>
            <heap>4000</heap>
        </resources>
    </cache>

</config>
```

and then in application.yml I have:

```
 cache:
    jcache:
      config: classpath:ehcache.xml
```